# jetpack compose - How do I cache signed URL from Cloudfront using Coil library

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, coil

**Usecase:**

I have a specific use-case, where I have to load signed URL from Cloudfront very frequently. Signed Cloudfront URL looks something like this:
`<base_url>/<filepath>?Expires=1692731643&Signature=sT-BagXsZkUnw....`

Since this image file is accessed very frequently in the app, I wanted to cache it in the disk with some custom key(like `<base_url>/<filepath>` since only GET parameters changes everytime. Can you please let me know how do I do this?

**Things I tried:**

This is how I have defined ImageLoader:

```
ImageLoader.Builder(this)
      .diskCache {
          DiskCache.Builder()
              .directory(this.cacheDir.resolve("image_cache"))
              .maxSizeBytes(2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)                     // 2 GB
              .build()
      }
      .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
      .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
      .crossfade(true)
      .build()
```

This is how I have defined ImageRequest:

```
val cachedImageURL = url.split("?").first()

    return ImageRequest.Builder(ctx)
        .data(url)
        .memoryCacheKey(cachedImageURL)
        .diskCacheKey(cachedImageURL)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
        .error(R.drawable.something_went_wrong)
        .diskCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
        .crossfade(true)
        .build()
```